# coq-HoTT: How to prove 1 < 2?

Tags: math, coq

I just would like to prove

```
Require Import HoTT. 
Open Scope nat. 

Lemma foo : 2 > 1.
```

in coq-HoTT. 
How to prove ? 
Or, what is the tactic corresponding to `auto` which proves its counterpart in coq?